# can i call a .net 2.0 dll in .net 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I am migrating to .net 3.5 and I want to know whether I can call from my 3.5 application, old .net 2.0 dll's methods?

Some external API's are in .net 2.0 dll. So I need those.

Kindly let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Old version of .net framework dll can be run in new version

Answer (score 10):

Yes. You can do that.

Answer (score 4):

.NET 3.5 is nothing more than .NET 2.0 SP2 with some additional assemblies. This means that .NET 3.5 *is* .NET 2.0, to a large extent.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, .NET remains compatible with old versions. There might be some obsolete code but it will still work. Only before 2.0 there can be compatibility issues.

Comment: And after 3.5 there are issues again as .net 4 introduced a new CLR. So we have 3 CLRs: .net 1.1, 2.0/3.0/3.5 and 4.0

Comment: However, even though 4.0 introduces a new CLR, 2.0 assemblies generally work in 4.0 too - though you may need to tweak the app's config file if they contain native code/interop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Genrally, you can run .Net 2.0 applications on a computer with newer versions of .Net, and using a DLL isn't different.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, both are managed code soit should work as calling .net 3.5 assembly.